# Upload files with Apache & PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I have installed a new Ubuntu 16.04 server and enabled PHP-FPM using [this](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=httpd&f=16) guide. I have also enabled the `userdir` module (so that I can have virtual sites running from a public_html folder under /home/$user) and `mod_ruid2`.

One of the things that has to be done according to the first guide is to add these three lines to 000-default.conf:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"
</FilesMatch>
```

With the tree lines added, my conf-file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName jrrtest
        RMode stat
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/jrr/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jrrtest-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jrrtest-access.log combined
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"
        </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

PHP is now executing as expected, but when I try to upload files using the examples on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) page, it is not working. If i try to upload a file I get this error in the Apache error_log:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/jorara.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/jrr/public_html/upload.php on line 38\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpAJsos1' to 'uploads/jorara.png' in /home/jrr/public_html/upload.php on line 38
```

If i remove the FilesMatch lines from 000-default.conf the upload functionality is working againg, but php is no longer executing using FastCGI as I want it to.

If I reenable the FilesMatch lines and change the owner on the uploads folder to `www-data:www-data` I can also get the upload functionality to work.

How can I configure PHP-FPM so that the owner of the php script can upload files to a folder owned by same owner as the script owner?

Regards,
Jørgen

Comment: What `FilesMatch lines`? What does `it is not working` mean - what are the error msgs, log messages?

Comment: The FilesMatch lines I'm referring to can be seen in the first guide I'm linking to (https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=httpd&f=16) and by `not working` I mean I get an error when I attempt to upload a file. The error in the Apache error_log is `PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/jorara.png): failed to open stream: Per
mission denied in /home/jrr/public_html/upload.php`.

Comment: Edit your question and add those details.  The more care you take providing all the details the better response you will get.  Nobody is going to go and read the tutorial to find out what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a couple of hours searching, I finally found a solution that seems to be working.

What I ended up doing was this.

Installed a standard Ubuntu with LAMP.

Installed these extra packages:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php7.0-fpm
```

Enabled these Apache modules:

```
a2enmod actions fastcgi
```

Created a couple of directories:

```
/var/www/testsite/htdocs
/var/www/testsite/phpsessions
/var/www/testsite/logs
```

Created a new php-fpm pool in the file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/testsite.conf:

```
[testsite]
    user = testsite
    group = testsite
    listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.testsite.sock
    listen.owner = www-data
    listen.group = www-data
    listen.mode = 0660

    pm = dynamic
    pm.max_children = 5
    pm.start_servers = 2
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1
    pm.max_spare_servers = 3

    php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /var/www/testsite/phpsessions
    php_admin_value[session.save_handler] = files
    php_admin_value[display_errors] = Off
    php_admin_value[log_errors] = On
    php_admin_value[error_log] = "/var/www/testsite/logs/php_error.log"
    php_admin_value[open_basedir] = "/var/www/testsite/htdocs:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/var/www/testsite/phpsessions"
```

In my first attempts with `listen.owner` and `listen.group` I had them set to `testsite`. That gave me problems accessing the socket file `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.testsite.sock` if I did not set `listen.mode` to `0666`. In my (and a lot of other peoples) opinion that is a security risk. Instead I enden up setting `listen.owner`, `listen.group` and `listen.mode` to the above shown values which seems to be the recommend solution.

Created a site definition in the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/testsite.conf with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php7-fcgi-testsite .php
    Action php7-fcgi-testsite /php7-fcgi-testsite
    Alias /php7-fcgi-testsite /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-testsite
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-testsite -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.testsite.sock -pass-header Authorization

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testsite

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testsite/htdocs

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/testsite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/testsite-access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/testsite/htdocs>
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            SetHandler php7-fcgi-testsite
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Enabled the new site:

```
a2ensite testsite
```

Disabled the default php module in Apache:

```
a2dismod php7.0
```

Restartet Apache and PHP-FPM:

```
systemctl restart php7.0-fpm apache2
```

The status of php-fpm (including the new pool) can be seen with this command:

```
systemctl status php7.0-fpm
```

Created the file info.php in /var/www/testsite/htdocs with this content:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Accessing testsite/info.php in a browser now shows that php is running as FastCGI which is what i wanted and files can be uploaded without problems.
[image: PHP as FPM/FastCGI]